# Variations and/or combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I've came across an interesting situation in my code and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything, so I'll try to explain it as simple as possible.

Imagine 4 buckets and 4 ping-pong balls, in how many variations can you put all balls in any of the buckets? The order of balls does not matter, all balls must be put into the buckets. (I came up with 35 possible situations)

Then a side question I have is the same but with 5 buckets and 5 balls. (I came up with 123 possible situations.)

Also, I'm interested in the number of possible combinations if you keep any amount of balls in the hand for each situation (with 4 buckets and 4 balls OR 5 buckets and 5 balls).

Comment: Does the order of the buckets matter?  Can you put one bucket inside another?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you wish to do is to distribute four indistinguishable ping pong balls among four distinguishable buckets (which, for instance, may be ordered from left to right in a row).  The number of ways to do this is the number of ways we can solve the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4$$ 
in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to a choice of where to place three addition signs in a row of four ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 + 1 + + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 0$, and $x_4 = 1$, while 
$$+ + 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, and $x_4 = 3$.  Thus, a solution amounts to a choice of which $3$ of $7$ symbols (corresponding to the four ones and three addition signs) will be addition signs.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{4 + 3}{3} = \binom{7}{3} = \frac{7!}{3!4!} = \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!}{4! \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 7 \cdot 5 = 35$$
ways, as you found.

The number of ways that five indistinguishable ping pong balls can be place in five distinguishable buckets is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5$$
By a similar argument to that given above, the number of ways we can do this is the number of ways we can place four addition signs in a row of five ones, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 4}{4} = \binom{9}{4} = \frac{9!}{4!5!} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!}{5! \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 126$$ 
which suggests that you missed three cases.

The number of ways we can distribute $n$ indistinguishable ping pong balls into $k$ distinguishable buckets is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers, which is the number of ways we can place $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$ 
ways.  When $k = n$, as in your examples, we obtain
$$\binom{2n - 1}{n - 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy question. This has already been answered on here, and a general form of this question would be the number of ways to order N indistinct objects into K indistinct containers.

This type of problem is defined by a recurrence relation since there is no closed form of this situation. I would suggest looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) to try to find the situation that fits your problem best.

Also, here is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278596/number-of-ways-to-put-n-indistinct-objects-into-m-indistinct-boxes) as already asked on here. Check it out and tell me if this is what you are asking!